# Unity: Detect if the Return or Done key was pressed in the native iOS keyboard

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, custom-keyboard

In **Unity3D**, how do I detect whether or not the return or done key of the `TouchScreenKeyboard` has been pressed?

I have tried `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm working on iOS and with the native iOS keyboard.

Comment: have you tried TouchScreenKeyboard.done? - I was just reading the documentation, I haven't test it.. in fact I don't have an IOs device to test, more like an Android user... let me know if it works...

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately, this method refers to when the Done button in the input field is tapped (among other end of input events), not the actual keyboard key. So this does not fit my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can send message to Unity by using [UnitySendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html) i.e. by calling it in your native `textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` method. It may seem unnecessary or burden, but if the other regular way (checking on Unity) does not work, it is the least i can offer.